# memory leak xerces use

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have a leak in my application and I've come to reduce my code to the following and it's leaking about 12kb per iteration.  I cannot see if this is a problem with my code or a problem with the xerces library itself.  But looking at the Private Bytes in Perfmon I can only see growth and no shrinkage, so it's obviously leaking.

Can someone please advice what could be wrong with the following code that causes it to leak at such an incredible rate?:

(single threaded test app)

```
for (int x = 0; x < 1000000; x++){
        DataSerializer* ds = new DataSerializer();
        ds->test(request);
        ds->releasedocument();
        ds->destroy_xml_lib();
        delete ds;
    }

void DataSerializer::test(std::string& request)
{
    impl = initialize_impl();
}
DOMImplementation* DataSerializer::initialize_impl()
{
    try
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock init_lock(impl_mtx);
        XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
        return DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation(XConv("Core"));
    }
    catch(const XMLException& toCatch)
    {
        char *pMsg = XMLString::transcode(toCatch.getMessage());
        std::string msg(pMsg);
        XMLString::release(&pMsg);
    }

    return NULL;
}
void DataSerializer::destroy_xml_lib()
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock terminate_lock (impl_mtx); //is being used in MT app
    XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate(); 
}
void DataSerializer::releasedocument()
{
    if (document){
        document->release();
        document = NULL;
    }
}
```

I don't understand how this could possibly leak?  What have I missed?

Comment: Maybe you could show more of the source code? For instance, how does the DataSerializer constructor look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where does `impl` get deleted?

I know nothing more about the API than googling the docs, but they suggest to me that you should not be calling `Terminate()` - in a real program, other code elsewhere, possibly in other threads, may still be using the xerces library.

The `DOMImplementation` is returned as a pointer and has a destructor - clear indications you have to manage its lifetime.  It seems a really *likely* story that that is your memory leak.

Furthermore, that the `DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation()` can return `NULL` so you have to guard against that.

If you can run this on Linux,use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (Purify is a commercial equivalent for windows)

Comment: Will: afaik this is supposed to delete impl: XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate();

Answer (score -1):

Not sure where you allocate `document`.
In the ReleaseDocument() function you don't delete it. All you do is set it to zero after clearing its content.

PS: don't know xerces either.